# Control module export in WPF by user rights

Tags: c#, wpf, mef

I'm developing an module based WPF app and I'm curious if there is an option to control module export with user rights?
I have 2 users which uses app with 3 modules, each user have rights to see or not to see those modules, f.ex. 1. user have rights to see only first 2 modules, and second one have rights to see only 1. and 3. module.
The rights are stored in database and downloaded at sync process and stored in xml config file (there is no problem with that, I think).
Modules are exported like: `[Export(typeof(MyBestViewModule))]` in each module project.
Or maybe there is some other way to control those modules by user rights? Best practices or something better, maybe someone has already done that an can share with the experience and idea, because I'm out of that.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a WPF problem but something more to do with an IoC/DependencyInjection framework - Unity / MEF or something like Prism.  Not really clear what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that you're using MEF, there's a way to filter modules via [`FilteredCatalog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.filteredcatalog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class ViewModulesCatalog : FilteredCatalog
{
    public ViewModulesCatalog(ComposablePartCatalog inner, IPermissionsProvider permissionsProvider)
        : base(inner, part => part.ExportDefinitions.All(def => permissionsProvider.IsAllowed(def)))
}
```

where `IPermissionsProvider` is a contract of your custom service, that checks permissions of current user. Something like this:

```
public interface IPermissionsProvider
{
    bool IsAllowed(ExportDefinition def);
}
```

**Update**.

If you're using Prism + `MefBootstrapper`, you have overridden method `ConfigureAggregateCatalog`:

```
// suppose assemblies with modules are located in "modules" subdir
var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@".\modules");
// let's filter directoryCatalog to get allowed modules
var permissionsProvider = // ... obtain provider reference here
var modulesCatalog = new ViewModulesCatalog(directoryCatalog, permissionsProvider);

return new AggregateCatalog(modulesCatalog);
```

Comment: sorry I don't really understand where to put this in my main project

Comment: Somewhere there's a place, where you are building MEF catalogs. You need to build a catalog from your modules, filter it, and after that add to MEF container.

Comment: I use MefBootstrapper...
By now I have Bootstrapper class which have overrided ConfigureAggregateCatalog() method and it selects all modules from project path into AggregateCatalog (probably you meant that)

Comment: OK... this looks good, now I'm curious where can I check the config file?
In config I have tag <UserModuleRights>110</UserModuleRights> each number is for one module if 1 then module should be visible...
I don't know, maybe this is also the dumbest way to store like this...

Comment: this is a bit heavy for me to understand, I haven't much worked with provider pattern and stuff, but what I did by now I created another class PermissionsProvider which inheritates IPermissionsProvider and created method IsAllowed, should I there do something with my config stuff? but what I need to pass in ExportDefinition place?

Comment: MEF catalog consists of "parts". For simplicity, your module is a part with a single export definition (`[Export(typeof())]`). FilteredCatalog allows you to setup a condition, when a part should be available in MEF container. In the sample, condition uses some class (permissions provider), to decide, whether to pass part or not. `ExportDefinition` is a MEF view of `[Export(...)]` attribute.

Comment: You should map particular `ExportDefinition` (`[Export(...)]`) to config. Somehow you have to know, that first "1" means "Module1" is available, second "1" - "Module2" is available, etc. You may either use module types (`ExportDefinition.ContractName`), or metadata to identify module in permissions provider logic.

Comment: yeah, hmm... looks like this is a bit complicated with saving in config like 110, probably best would be in separate tags each module and in module registration just check if the module is in the config...
And I didn't also understand that mapping, how can I map them with ExportDefinition...